# Can't change State from child component even after passing a function from parent component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, state

Currently making a to-do app that has a welcome screen at first, but when clicked the button enter, it'll setState welcome from true to false. triggering the actual todo list component.

For some reason even after passing down the function to WelcomePage, React still wont render to the other component when I press enter.

Thank you,

```
function Router(props) {
    if (props.welcome) {
        return <WelcomePage onEnter={props.onEnter}/> //if home is true, there will be home page rendered
    } else { 
        return <ToDoPage/> //if home is false, that means you've entered
    }
}


class ToDo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {welcome: true};
        this.onEnter = this.onEnter.bind(this);
    }

    onEnter(e) {
        this.setState({welcome: false});
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="ToDo">
                    <Router welcome={this.state.welcome} onEnter={this.onEnter}/>
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

```
class WelcomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="home">
                <h1> Welcome</h1>
                <h2> Who does this list beong to? </h2>
                <input placeholder="your name"/>
                <input type="button" value="enter" onSubmit={this.props.onEnter}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean won't recognize? Is there a specific error, like cannot call method of null or something?

Comment: I'm not sure, i think it's not registering the function. I can't get it to change the component when i press enter.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are trying to add a submit event handler to a button? Did you mean onClick? Or did you mean to make a form and handle the submit of the form?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky oh you solved it, I made a mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `onSubmit` to `onClick` as `input:button` does not emit `submit` events:

```
class WelcomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="home">
                <h1> Welcome</h1>
                <h2> Who does this list beong to? </h2>
                <input placeholder="your name"/>
                <input type="button" value="enter" onClick={this.props.onEnter}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```